ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'libcamera'
I have a Zero 2W and OS Lite 32-Bit inside. All I want is a python program that sends camera footage with UDP protocol and saves footage SD card inside as a video.
So I wrote this program which worked just fine for Raspberry Pi 4 with an OS (can't remember) 64-bit.
https://github.com/Sokisati/camera_epl
But I no matter what I do, I just can't seem to get it working. I did everything, every way. Re-installed OS just in case I broke something. Nope. Still the same error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/glados/myenv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/picamera2/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    import libcamera
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'libcamera'

I am sure I succesfully installed picamera2.
What might be causing this and how can I solve it? Or is there a very detailed tutorial I can follow for my OS Lite 32-Bit?

I'm having the same issue--Giwby, I think you're misunderstanding, picamera2 depends on libcamera, so it's actually what's throwing the issue. The libcamera error we're both seeing is a nested error in the import statement for picamera2. If anyone has solved this, I would love to know how.

Does libcamera-hello throw any errors?

In my code I use import picamera
https://picamera.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.13/

They code in the GitHub repo you linked to uses import picamera2 not import libcamera. I think you are referring to the wrong module. If you do indeed want to use libcamera, whether or not you have successfully installed picamera2 is somewhat irrelevant. You should attempt to install libcamera.
